# anything vs nothing as in 'you still understand nothing'

Tags: anything-vs-nothing

You're exasperated with someone failing to understand something

Would you say:

1. You still understand nothing.
   or
2. You still don't understand anything.

I reckon they mean the same, and perhaps more than the words the pointedness of these sentences can depend more on the tone of the speaker.

Is 1. in casual conversations more common the the latter? I feel like it is. Especially when we don't want to be too harsh on the receiver of the utterance, although we already are to a degree.

Would, e.g. a person wrongly accused of stealing something be more likely to say:
3. I've stolen nothing or 4. I haven't stolen anything.  I think that if that person were in anger because no one believes them they would probably go for I've stolen nothing. Is your feeling the same?

Comment: They both do mean the same thing. 1) is more **forceful**.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if there's two equivalent sentences, one with "nothing" and the other with "not ... anything", the one with "nothing" will feel stronger, possibly harsher.

This is true for your example sentences.

That said, even, "You still don't understand anything" is quite a strong thing to say, and will probably sound condescending. The version with "nothing" is stronger -- both condescending and maybe frustrated or dismissive.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, they're completely equal in meaning, formality level, and so on. No difference.

I'd say it sounds somewhat smoother to me to put the negative closer to the start of the sentence, rather than at the end. The farther from one position to the other, the more I'd tend to say my "not" sooner rather than later. (Unless I'm going for dramatic buildup. Then I'd save it for the end.)

Especially in the case of someone who's just been accused of stealing, I'd want to claim innocence as quickly as possible, in case I don't get to say anything long before the accuser throws a punch.